# after API PUT call and then API GET call, component is not getting updated data

Tags: angular, typescript, api

I am doing API PUT call and then I want to load the updated data, So I am doing API GET call on the same component (first PUT then GET). But it is not displaying updated data which i have done from PUT call. I have to reload the page to see updated data. I am using JSON-SERVER for API.

Comment: just make get oninit() so you have displayed what is in DB
and then after put make ngoninit() ;)

Comment: I have already tried this too. At first I did API PUT call and then called onInit() too. But nothing changed.

Comment: so you need to create stackBlits or post all code here

Comment: Well Can't share the code or stackblitz it.

Comment: try `setTimeout(()=>{ this.getMethod()},200)`

Comment: I have tried setTimeOut. It is not working

Comment: is the GET call happening only after success of PUT? note the asynchronous nature of HTTP calls

Comment: Please show the code you are having issue with. Show both functions you are calling, the component code you are using.

Comment: @NithinKumarBiliya Yes, actually I was not calling GET on success of PUT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As no code is provided in the question i am guessing that you are not calling GET after PUT is finished.

If you write

```
PUT CALL
GET CALL
```

It will never work. If you write

```
PUT CALL
setTimeout(() => {
    GET CALL
}, 200);
```

It is not guaranteed that you will get updated data. Correct way of calling would be

```
PUT CALL.subscribe(() => {
    GET CALL
});
```

It guaranties that GET will be called after PUT is finished.

Comment: Yes, there was my mistake. I was calling GET without taking care of response of PUT call. Thanks!